# Build set using hash-map on C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, hashmap

I'm trying to build set using hash-map, but testing system sends me wrong answers. I don't have access to tests, but on my tests code works fine. I don't have any ideas for new tests, maybe you'll have some?
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int h1(int number) {
    number %= 1000003;
    return abs(number);
}

int h2(int number) {
    number = number % 999991 + 12;
    return abs(number);
}

int Insert(int * Hash_table,bool * Deleted,int& number) {
    int x = h1(number);
    int y = h2(number);
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000003;i++) {
        if(Hash_table[x] == NULL || Deleted[x]) {
            Hash_table[x] = number;
            Deleted[x] = false;
            break;
        }
        x = (x + i * y) % 1000003;
    }
}

string Exists(int * Hash_table,bool * Deleted,int& number) {
    int x = h1(number);
    int y = h2(number);
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000003;i++) {
        if(Hash_table[x] == 0 && number == 0 && !Deleted[x])
            return "true\n";
        if(Hash_table[x] != NULL) 
            if(Hash_table[x] == number && !Deleted[x] ) {
                return "true\n";
            }
        if(Hash_table[x] == NULL || Deleted[x])
            return "false\n";

        x = (x + i * y) % 1000003;

    }

}
int Delete(int * Hash_table,bool * Deleted,int& number){
    int x = h1(number);
    int y = h2(number);
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000003;i++){
        if(Hash_table[x] == 0 && number == 0){
            Deleted[x] = true;
            break;
        }
        if(Hash_table[x] != NULL) {
            if(Hash_table[x] == number) {
                Deleted[x] = true;
                break;
            }

         x = (x + i * y) % 1000003;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
}

int main () {
    int Hash_table[1000003];
    bool Deleted[1000003];
    ifstream input("set.in");
    ofstream output("set.out");
    string command;
    int number;
    while(true) {
        input >> command;
        if(input.eof())
            break;
        if(command == "insert") {
            input >> number;
            Insert(Hash_table,Deleted,number);
        }
        if(command == "delete") {
            input >> number;
            Delete(Hash_table,Deleted,number);
        }
        if(command == "exists") {
            input >> number;
            output << Exists(Hash_table,Deleted,number);
        }
    }
}
```

I have to realise such commands as "input","exists" and "delete". I think logic of code is nice, but I'm not sure about hash functions.
Updated: Add if statements for 0 and now h1 and h2 return absolute values.
But now I have problems in 4th test.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Talk us through the sorts of local testing that you've done on your end. If you haven't written any local tests, I'd start there - it's much, much easier to debug things when you can see what the program is doing and how the behavior differs from what you expect than it is to submit code to a black box testing framework and hope that it turns out well.

Comment: Okay, for example, code works fine for such test:
insert 2
insert 5
insert 3
exists 2
exists 4
insert 2
delete 2
exists 2
Output:
true
false
false

Comment: (1) `int Hash_table[1000003];` is seriously dangerous. Stack is small, life is short, allocate dynamically. (2) What about 0? Is it a number? `insert 0` then `exists 0`.

Comment: (1) I know limit of number of input numbers (1000000), that's why I used const value. (2) Yes, with 0 my code doesn't work, it's because of NULL? How can I change if operators without using NULL?

Comment: s/`NULL`/`nullptr`/

Comment: I fixed problem with 0 (passed one test), by adding if statements when number == 0, and now I get runtime error.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Do you have to use hash maps? Can you use the builtin `std::unordered_map` or `std::map`? `std::set`?

Comment: It's an algorithm task to build your own set using hash-tables. I can't use <map> or <set>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int h1(int number) {
    number %= 1000003;
    return number;
}

int h2(int number) {
    number = number % 99991 + 1;
    return number;
}
```

Abouve function will give negative output for negative number. That will cause runtime error for `Hash_table[x]`. See below:

```
int h1(int number) {
    number = (number%1000003 + 1000003) % 1000003;
    return number;
}

int h2(int number) {
    number = (number % 99991 + 99991) % 99991 + 1;
    return number;
}
```